# Master-Detail Usage

Tags: android, master-detail

I am building an app in which I show a list of reports in the master part and when I select one I want to execute the associated activity and display its output in the detail section of the m-d layout. This is not the usual way in which the m-d pattern is used and I'm not even sure this is a good way to use it.  I would appreciate any opinion and advice.

Comment: I should have said that the report list is retrieved from a database table and each actual report module required additional db accesses to produce the actual report.

Comment: You can't run an activity and display it in a frame of you current one.  A new activity will take over.  What you want is a fragment.

Comment: If you are using mater/detail you should be using fragments and you just change the fragment in the detail view

Comment: Thanks. I'd got it workingjust fine, and thx for your response.